# How to get current time in datetime format in XML file of odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

My code is as follows....

My Model is ...

```
class Today_Status(models.Model):
    _name = 'today.status'

    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    starttime = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='book.meeting')
```

My XML file is as follows...

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="dashboard-menu">
    <field name="name">DashBoard</field>
    <field name="res_model">today.status</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[("start_time", ">=", "current_time")]</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="dash-view"/>
 </record>
```

I want to get current time in XML or i want to use the variable current_time specified in model in the XML file. How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to set the below domain and then check your module after upgrading your module.

```
[('date','>=', ((context_today()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))+' '+'00:00:00'),('date','&lt;=', ((context_today()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))+' '+'23:59:59')]
```

Also add a new datetime field  as date in your model.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer was very useful. But i think no need of double percentage symbol (%%) Only single is required here ('%%Y-%%m-%%d')